How can I perform write operations to my Amazon RDS for Postgres DB instance read replica?
How can I perform write operations to my Amazon RDS for Postgress instance read replica?
some similar solution as for mysql/maria db is given in this post
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-read-replica
I am trying to create new data base in read replica so that i can dump some analytics data in that database for reporting purpose and that data wont be shown on primary database.
I tried this by changing some DB parameters for replica but it wont let me do write operations

Postgres does not allow replica/slave for writes.Only master supports writes.Therefore you cannot create database on read-replica.
